# Xslt Remove only empty tags without any attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new  in the xml and xslt programming and transformation . I'm writing an xslt to remove empty tags within a xml document .

The xslt I'm usins is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:if test=". != ''">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:element name="name()">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that when I transform my xml document with the above xslt also tags containing not empty attributes are removed . 
For example , with my xslt I want to remove tags like :

```
<tag1></tag1>
```

or

```
<tag1\>
```

but NOT

```
<tag1 attribute1="some value" attribute2="" ....></tag1>
```

Can you help me to find the best way to modify the xslt in order to achieve the described behaviour ?

Thanks in advance ,

Answer (score 1):

Change your test to this:

```
<xsl:if test=". != '' or @*">
```

This says "If the node has contents or if it has any attributes then"

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to remove empty nodes that don't have attributes then I would start with the identity template and then create another template that matches these nodes you want removed and just do nothing with them.

So that would look like the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/node()[not(@*) and not(text() !='')]">
</xsl:template>
```

When run against this XML:

```
<root>
  <tag1></tag1>
  <tag1/>
  <tag1 attribute="value"></tag1>
  <tag1>value</tag1>
</root>
```

Creates this output:

```
<root>
  <tag1 attribute="value"/>
  <tag1>value</tag1>
</root>
```